# Cast of a string to a number is failing on Azure MSSQL environment

Tags: sql-server, hibernate, azure-sql-database

> CAST(A.version AS integer)

is failing with below error -

> SQL Error: 243, SQLState: S0001
>   org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.logExceptions Type
>   signed is not a defined system type.

### Sample data in Table A -

```
id    key          version
1    'advanced/x'  '1'
2    'advanced/x'  '2'
3    'basic'       '1'
```

Now, I need the key and version of the latest version record under advanced category(key).

### Query -

> SELECT A.key, MAX(CAST(A.version AS integer)) FROM Table A where A.key like 'advanced%' GROUP BY A.key";

### Sample output -

```
key             version
'advanced/x'    '2'
```

While the same query is working fine on a generic SQL server.
'version' is a string and I need it to typecast to a number.
Can someone please help me on how to resolve this issue?

Comment: Please show us some data, and also the context of the cast in an actual query.

Comment: Please try this CAST([A.version] AS integer)

Comment: Syntax for CAST:   CAST ( expression AS data_type [ (length ) ])

Comment: @tim Actual query updated inline.
version holds values like '1.0.0', '1.2.5', '2.0' etc. I am trying to fetch the highest version number from 'n' number of records whose 'key' starts with 'dummy' and has '1342' as 'id'.

Comment: This is tough because there are subversions as well.  If the depth of the versioning is fixed (e.g. 3), then I recommend using separate columns for each number component of the version.

Comment: @Tim  I'm using the same query for multiple dbs and is working fine. But now I wanted to support that use case on Azure cloud with MSSQL as well which is failing. Why is the issue on Azure MSSQL and not on a generic MSSQL? My doubt is how is the internal implementation differ for both?

Comment: `1.2.5` is not an integer, and ideally attempting to convert it to an integer should produce an error.  You are trying to sort according to a hierarchy, and a simple cast won't work.

Comment: okay. Consider values of type '1.0.0' only. In that case? @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: So are you saying you want to sort based on the first number only?

Comment: Or just consider values of fixed depth like '1'

Comment: yes. Consider version holds only one level depth numbers (eg. '1') and now I want to sort them @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: Please add some sample data to your question, and then show us what sorting output you want.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Please find the updated sample data.

Comment: Other than that you need to escape the column key as `[key]`, your query is working fine.  [See the demo here](http://rextester.com/LBA44008).